# Flip Horizontally Through the Context Menu in the Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, contextmenu, microsoft-file-explorer

When I right-click on an image in the Windows 10 File Explorer, I get the option to either rotate right or rotate left in the context menu, but not to flip horizontally. I instead click edit, which opens up Paint, and I flip my images one at a time. This is very time consuming, and it would be really convenient to be able to bulk flip a bunch of images with a single click.

Answer (score 1):

Registry File RotateNoneFlipX.reg

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RotateNoneFlipX]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RotateNoneFlipX\command]
@="PowerShell.exe -File "C:\RotateNoneFlipX.ps1" -path "%V" "

The RotateNoneFlipX.ps1 PowerShell Script in C:\RotateNoneFlip.ps1

```
param([string]$path)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
Get-ChildItem -recurse ($path) -include @("*.png", "*.jpg") |
ForEach-Object {
  $image = [System.Drawing.image]::FromFile( $_ )
  $image.rotateflip("RotateNoneFlipX")
  $image.save($_)
}
```

Use:
Select Folder in File Explorer, Right-Click and Select RotateNoneFlipX command to flip all png en jpg files in folder

Comment: `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\RotateNoneFlipX\command] @="PowerShell.exe -File \"C:\\RotateNoneFlip.ps1\" -path \"%V\""` is the correct syntax for the .reg file